# Tkinter Spinbox using get value in command function

Tags: python, tkinter, get

I am trying to write some code that populates a spinbox with file names (of .png images) in a directory. Then on selecting one item in the spinbox display the image. I am having trouble passing the value from the spinbox with get

The resulting error is:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file=XS_Spinbox.get())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Noting that  hard coding the file name works...

```
photo = PhotoImage(file='Arm_DEM_192_XSplot.png')
```

.

```
XS_Spinbox = Spinbox(myframe2, values = ([x for x in os.listdir(os.curdir) if os.path.splitext(x)[1] in ('.png')]), command=update_photoImage).pack()

def update_photoImage():
#print XS_spinBox.get()
#photo = PhotoImage(file=XS_spinBox.get())
photo = PhotoImage(file=XS_Spinbox.get())
label.image = photo
return
```

Comment: I think this question is more about how Tkinter widget spinbox passes values to command functions ?

Comment: def update_photoImage():
    print XS_Spinbox.get()
    photo = PhotoImage(file = XS_Spinbox.get())
    photo = photo.subsample(2,2)
    #label = Label(myframe2, image=photo)
    label.configure(image = photo)
    label.image = photo
    print 'Image updated ...'
    return                                                                               This successfully updates the image using the spinbox.get data

Answer (score 0):

`pack()` returns `None` and you assign it to `XS_Spinbox`.

You have to do in two steps:

```
 XS_Spinbox = Spinbox(...)

 XS_Spinbox.pack()
```

Comment: I have now adjusted as a two step assignment but although the Spinbox data is being updated the image is not updating in the function         def update_photoImage():
    print XS_Spinbox.get()
    photo = PhotoImage(file = XS_Spinbox.get())
    photo = photo.subsample(2,2)
    label = Label(myframe2, image=photo)
    label.image = photo
    return         Just wondering how the image in the label is updated ????

Comment: did you run in console ? maybe you get error message. You may have to add `os.curdir` to filename to have full path.

Comment: and you have to do `label["image"] = photo` or `label.config(image=photo)`